# Swift - Pass data from parent view controller to child view controller

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to retrieve my eventId from my parent view controller to the child controller. But it seems that my child view controller is being instantiated before the parent. How can I get that eventId from my child controller? Thank you

I'm passing data from my EventsMainController to EventsDetails(Parent Controller)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "eventDetails" {
            let DestViewController : EventDetailsViewController = segue.destination as! EventDetailsViewController

            DestViewController.eventId = myEvents[index].uuid

        }

    }
```

Then in my EventsDetail Controller I have my variable where I can retrieve it. EventsDetails is my parent controller where I have my child controller in it.

```
 var eventId = String()
```

In my child controller I'm using this to retrieve the id. It's returning nil.

```
    var eventId = String()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print(eventId)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your segue identifier is "eventDetails"? It's passing trough this? DestViewController.eventId = myEvents[index].uuid

Comment: It seems that you are talking about three controllers: `EventsMainController`, `EventsDetails` and a *child controller*. What is the latter one?

Comment: @iDevid Yes, I'm getting all my infos I need in EventDetails when I'm using segue identifier "evenDetails"

Comment: @vadian The child controller is called InvitedViewController. EventDetails is the parent. I'm passing data from EventsMain to Event Details then to InvitedController (child)

Comment: Then the crucial part is the code to pass the data from Details to Invited and not the code in the question

Comment: @Ziyaad Show how you added InvitedController to EventDetails

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I did it on Storyboard using containers

Comment: So you should use segues to pass data trough your child from EventDetails

Comment: @iDevid I need to show the parent view along the EvenDetails. Hence it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a `Container View` in storyboard it adds a child view controller and a segue from the parent view controller to child view controller.

[image]

This segue is performed immediately after the parent view controller is loaded. Pass the data from `EventDetails` to `InvitedController` in `prepare for segue` method

```
class EventsMainController: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "EventDetails" {
            if let eventDetails = segue.destination as? EventDetails {
                eventDetails.eventId = "FromEventsMainController"
            }
        }
    }
}
class EventDetails: UIViewController {
    var eventId = String()
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {    
        if segue.identifier == "InvitedController" {
            if let invitedController = segue.destination as? InvitedController {
                invitedController.eventId = self.eventId
            }
        }
    }
}
class InvitedController: UIViewController {
    var eventId = String()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(eventId)//FromEventsMainController
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I didn't about know about the parent and child view relationship segue. Thank you very much :)